# Javascript Rotate player by pressing keys

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am making a simple `JS` & `HTML` Canvas space shooter.
I thought it would be cool to rotate the player(rect) by pressing `E` or `Q` keys.

nothing hard right?

so I made canvas and player as object with its functions.
one of its functions is rotate(direction), right now it should rotate by 45deg but it doesn't.

anyway here is the code :

(thx for help)

```js
const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
let body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
body.appendChild(canvas);
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = innerWidth;
canvas.height = innerHeight;
canvas.style.backgroundColor = "black";
canvas.innerHTML = "your browser does not support HTML5! Please upgrade";
window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
  canvas.width = innerWidth;
  canvas.height = innerHeight;
});

let qPressed = false,ePressed = false;

const player = {
    x:canvas.width/2-25,
    y:canvas.height/2-25,
    w:50,
    h:50,
    score:0,
    hp : 100,
    create : function(){
        ctx.fillStyle = "pink";
        ctx.fillRect(this.x,this.y,this.w,this.h);
    },
    holdInScreen : function(){
        if (this.x < 0) {
            this.x = canvas.width;
          } else if (this.x - 50 > canvas.width) {
            this.x = 0;
          } else if (this.y < 0) {
            this.y = canvas.height;
          } else if (this.y > canvas.height) {
            this.y = 0;
          }
    },
    rotate : function(direction){
        if(direction == "left"){
            ctx.save(); 
            ctx.translate(this.x + this.w, this.y); 
            ctx.rotate(Math.PI / 4); 
            ctx.restore(); 
        }else{

        }
    },
    keyHandler : function(){
          if(ePressed){
            this.rotate("right");
          }else if(qPressed){
            this.rotate("left");
          }
    },
    giveScore : function(){
        return this.score;
    },
    getHit : function(){
        if(this.hp <= 0){
            console.log("game over!");
        }else{
            this.hp -= 25;
        }
    },
    update:function(){
        this.holdInScreen();
        this.keyHandler();

    }
}

const update = function(){

    player.update();

}
const render = function(){

    player.create();
}
let id;
const Loop = function(){
    id = requestAnimationFrame(Loop);
    update();
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    render();
}
Loop()
window.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
  if(e.keyCode == 69) ePressed = true;
  if(e.keyCode == 81) qPressed = true;
})
window.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
  if(e.keyCode == 69) ePressed = true;
  if(e.keyCode == 81) qPressed = true;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
let body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
body.appendChild(canvas);
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = innerWidth - 20;
canvas.height = innerHeight - 20;
canvas.style.backgroundColor = "black";
canvas.innerHTML = "your browser does not support HTML5! Please upgrade";
window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
  canvas.width = innerWidth - 40;
  canvas.height = innerHeight - 40;
});

let qPressed = false,ePressed = false;

const player = {
    x:canvas.width/2-25,
    y:canvas.height/2-25,
    w:50,
    h:50,
    angle: 0,
    score:0,
    hp : 100,
    create(){
        ctx.save();
        // Translate coords to the center of square..
        ctx.translate(this.x + this.w/2, this.y + this.h/2);
        // Rotate..
        ctx.rotate(this.angle);
        // Fill..
        ctx.fillStyle = "pink";
        // Remember coords are translated
        ctx.fillRect(-this.w/2, -this.h/2, this.w, this.h);
        ctx.restore();
    },
    holdInScreen : function(){
        if (this.x < 0) {
            this.x = canvas.width;
          } else if (this.x - 50 > canvas.width) {
            this.x = 0;
          } else if (this.y < 0) {
            this.y = canvas.height;
          } else if (this.y > canvas.height) {
            this.y = 0;
          }
    },
    rotate(direction) {
        // Dont draw anything here, just change the angle
        if(direction == "left") {
          this.angle += .02;
        }else{
          this.angle -= .02;
        }
    },
    keyHandler(){
          if(ePressed){
            this.rotate("right");
          }else if(qPressed){
            this.rotate("left");
          }
    },
    giveScore(){
        return this.score;
    },
    getHit(){
        if(this.hp <= 0){
            console.log("game over!");
        }else{
            this.hp -= 25;
        }
    },
    update(){
        this.holdInScreen();
        this.keyHandler();
    }
}

const Loop = function(){
    player.update();
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    player.create();
    requestAnimationFrame(Loop);
}
Loop();

window.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
  if(e.keyCode == 69) ePressed = true;
  if(e.keyCode == 81) qPressed = true;
})
window.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
  if(e.keyCode == 69) ePressed = false;
  if(e.keyCode == 81) qPressed = false;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create: function () {
    ctx.fillStyle = "pink";
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
},

rotate: function (direction) {
    if (direction == "left") {
        ctx.save();
        ctx.translate(this.x + this.w, this.y);
        ctx.rotate(Math.PI / 4);
        ctx.restore();
    } else {

    }
},
```

You need to rotate the canvas then draw the player.
You're currently

- rotating the canvas and resetting the context
- drawing the player

When really it should be

- translate the canvas to where you want the object to be
- rotate the canvas
- draw the player

Edited your code slighly and removed the keyup listener.

```
const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
let body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
body.appendChild(canvas);
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = innerWidth;
canvas.height = innerHeight;
canvas.style.backgroundColor = "black";
canvas.innerHTML = "your browser does not support HTML5! Please upgrade";
window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
  canvas.width = innerWidth;
  canvas.height = innerHeight;
});

const player = {
  x: canvas.width / 2 - 25,
  y: canvas.height / 2 - 25,
  w: 50,
  h: 50,
  score: 0,
  hp: 100,
  rotation: 0,
  
  // Originally our create() function changed the name
  drawPlayer: function () {
    ctx.fillStyle = "pink";
    ctx.save();

    // Translate to center
    ctx.translate(this.x + this.w/2, this.y + this.h/2);

    // Rotate canvas based on rotation value
    ctx.rotate(this.rotation * Math.PI / 180);

    // Draw square
    ctx.fillRect(-this.w/2, -this.h/2, this.w, this.h);

    ctx.restore();
  },

  // Pressing 'q' or 'e' would result in updating the rotation
  rotate: function (direction) {
    if (direction === 'left') {
      console.log('left');
      this.rotation -= 45;
    } else if (direction === 'right') {
      console.log('right');
      this.rotation += 45;
    }
  },
}

let id;

const Loop = function () {
  id = requestAnimationFrame(Loop);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  player.drawPlayer();
}

Loop()

// Updated to call player rotate without the need to check for flags
document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
  console.log(e.keyCode);
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 69:
      console.log('key right');
      player.rotate("right");
      break;
    case 81:
      console.log('key left');
      player.rotate("left");
      break;
    default:
      // Do nothing for other keys
      break;
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you for explanation and for help